# Test if two iterators come from same object

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

Given two std::iterators of the same type, how is it possible to test if the come from the same object (not class)? Note, I'm not asking how to compare their values.

```
std::string foo = "foo";
std::string bar = "bar";

std::string::iterator iter1 = foo.begin();
std::string::iterator iter2 = bar.begin();

if ( iter1 == iter2 )
{
    ...
}
```

The above should and does fail. How can I check for this at runtime? Looking into the source code, I see that the relevant methods call on `iterator::_Compat()` this is a void method that does the check I want but on failure it issues a debug assertation. It will go unnoticed in release builds.

Looking further I see that the iterator (for string at least) has a public `_GetCont()` method. So

```
if ( iter1._GetCont() == iter2._GetCont() )
```

works. But, this is undocumented leading me to believe it's not safe to use.

My question is how can I accomplish the above in a portable manner?

Also to note, this is part of an iterator template class. I will have no control over the second iterator.

Comment: Like you guessed, those `_Compat` and `_GetCont` functions are completely implementation-dependent and likely not present (or named differently) in other implementations. Off the top of my head I don't see a platform-independent way for checking this (since the iterator doesn't even need to have a reference to the container at all, and in release most probably won't, i.e. this `_GetCont` shouldn't even work in release mode). Good question, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> My question is how can I accomplish the above in a portable manner?

You cannot.

In general, iterators are not required to know (or let *you* know) about the container they point into. Iterators are a generalization of pointers, and all they are required to do is to behave like pointers.

So they may allow dereferencing, incrementing, decrementing, summing, and so on, depending on their category, but there is no iterator requirement in the C++ Standard about letting their user know what container they point into, or whether they point into the same container as another iterator.

In other words, the validity of an iterator range should be a *precondition* of a function that works on that iterator range. It is a responsibility of the client to ensure the provided iterators point into the same container (and that the second iterator is reachable from the first).

For instance, here is how the Standard Library deals with this matter (paragraph 24.2.1/7 of the C++11 Standard):

> Most of the library’s algorithmic templates that operate on data structures have interfaces that use ranges.
>   A range is a pair of iterators that designate the beginning and end of the computation. A range `[i,i)` is an
>   empty range; in general, a range `[i,j)` refers to the elements in the data structure starting with the element
>   pointed to by `i` and up to but not including the element pointed to by `j`. Range `[i,j)` is valid if and only if
>   `j` is reachable from `i`. **The result of the application of functions in the library to invalid ranges is undefined**.

Comment: I understand. Here's my predicament: I've written a template class that handles conversions between utf encoding schemes. It's basically a wrapper around the standard std::string::iterators. It must behave exactly like the underlying iterator except convert codepoints on the fly. The problem arose when implementing the inequality relational operators. I was hoping to throw an exception if the two iterators are unrelated, but now I see that even STL doesn't do that.

Comment: @Waldermort: Indeed, just rely on Undefined Behavior ;)

Answer (score -1):

You may want to compare pointers

```
if ( &(*iter1) == &(*iter2) )
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: That only tests if they point to the same memory, not if they came from the same object.